# Android : Checkboxes and ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a ListView with checkboxes in it.
When I click on a element of the ListView, it does not check/uncheck the checkbox. I want to toggle the checkbox if the user clicks on the checkbox or on the listview.

How can I do that ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listen for the click event and adjust the state of the `CheckBox`.  The `onClick` gives you the `View` that was clicked so you should be able to get the `CheckBox` easily.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the click listener of CheckBox in each row of list view, you can add the setOnCheckedChangeListener of checkbox in getView() method of your custom adapter.